# Mysterious side-effect of calling printf or not in C before calling an asm function?

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

This program has to calculate pi with accuracy provided by the user.
The calculate_pi () function is written in NASM.
Can someone explain to me why if this line is commented:

```
//printf("accuracy: %.15f\n", precision);       //<- This line
```

The program does not work correctly. Send strange numbers to the calcuta_pi() function?   If this line is commented, a very small value is sent to the function and the program runs infinitely.

But if it is not a commented program works correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

extern double calculate_pi(double precision); /* external function declaration */

double calculate_pi(double precision);   /* function prototype */

int main()
{
double precision = 1;

printf("A program that calculates pi, with accuracy provided by the user\n");
printf("Give me accuracy\n");

while(1)
{
    if (scanf("%lf", &precision) != 1)
    {
        printf("reading error\n");

        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

        continue;
    }
    if(precision<0)
        precision = fabs(precision);

    //printf("accuracy: %.15f\n", precision);       //<- This line
    printf("pi: %.15f\n", calculate_pi(precision));
}

return 0;
}
```

This is my assembly code:

```
;   arctg(1)=a
;   tg(arctg(1))=tg(a)
;   atan(x) = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - x^7/7 + x^9/9..
;   PI/4 = atan(1) = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9...
;   PI = (4/1) - (4/3) + (4/5) - (4/7) + (4/9) - (4/11) + (4/13) - (4/15) ...


section .text use32

global  _calculate_pi

_calculate_pi:

%idefine    a   [ebp+12]


;ramka stosu
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp

;ustawianie zmiennych
fld qword [const_wynik]
fstp qword [wynik]

fld qword [const_licznik]
fstp qword [licznik]

fld qword [const_mianownik]
fstp qword [mianownik]

.loop:
finit ; inicjalizacja stosu FPU

fld qword [licznik]         ;licznik na stos
fld qword [mianownik]       ;mianownik na stos
fdiv                        ;wynik dzielenia st1/st0
fadd qword [wynik]          ;st0 = wynik dzielenia + [wynik]

fstp qword [wynik]          ;wywalamy z st0 do [wynik]

                            ;zmieniamy mianownik + 2
fld qword [mianownik]       ;mianownik na stos
fadd qword [zwiekszmian]    ;st0 = mianownik + 2
fstp qword [mianownik]          ;wywalamy z st0 do [mianownik]

                            ;zmieniamy licznik *(-1)
fld qword [licznik]         ;licznik na stos
fchs                        ;st0 = -st0 = -licznik
fstp qword [licznik]        ;wywalamy z st0 do [licznik]

                        ;sprawdzanie dokladnosci
fld qword[wynik]        ;wynik na stos
fldpi                   ;pi na stos
fsub                    ;st0 = wynik-pi = st1 - st0
fabs                    ;st0 = |wynik-pi|

fld qword a             ;st0 = zadana dokladnosc

                            ;(Unordered Compare ST(0) to ST(i) and set CPU flags and Pop ST(0))
                            ;Przyrostek p oznacza obniżenie stosu rejestrów koprocesora, przyrostek i oznacza zapisywanie wyników bezpośrednio do flag procesora a nie flag koprocesora
fucomip st0, st1            ;porownanie z dokladnoscia  if(zadana dokladnosc > uzyskana)


jb    .loop   ;only the C0 bit (CF flag) would be set if no error


fld qword [wynik]

        ;zwraca to co w st0
leave   ; LEAVE = mov esp, ebp / pop ebp
ret


section .data:

wynik       dq 4.0
licznik     dq -4.0
mianownik   dq 3.0
zwiekszmian dq 2.0

const_wynik     dq 4.0
const_licznik   dq -4.0
const_mianownik dq 3.0
```

Sample output:

[image]

I'm using:

- NASM version 2.11.06 compiled on Oct 20 2014
- gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Compilation and assembler commands:

```
nasm -o pi.o -f coff pi.asm
gcc pi.o pi_interface.c -o projekt.exe -Wall -Wextra
```

Comment: That's not a very user-friendly way of specifying accuracy. Number of correct digits would be more expected.

Comment: Please explain in which way it does not work correctly.

Comment: The program does not work correctly when:
The calculate_pi () function calculates pi with the taylor formula for arctg (1).
If this line comments, a very small value is sent to the function and the program runs infinitely.

Comment: seems like the assembly functions doesn't follow the correct calling convention of your target platform, and with the `printf` code ahead of assembly call you get lucky, and pick correct value by accident. Try to check in debugger how the entry state differs between the two. You didn't even show the declaration of `calculate_pi` function, nor it's asm source, do you think we are oracles here? :D (downvoting because of not even getting close to [MCVE], at a point, when you are wasting everyone's time)

Comment: @Ped7g: the correct response is a close-vote with that reason.  Downvoting for lack of an MCVE is an option, but it makes little sense to do that without actually close-voting (unless you're saving your close-vote for a duplicate).

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time in this forum

extern double calculate_pi(double precision); /* external function declaration */

double calculate_pi(double precision);  /* function prototype */

Comment: Clearly the asm has a bug, and different C source leaves different values in registers which the code shouldn't be depending on.  If you look at compiler output (for whatever compiler you're using...) you could see what the difference is and that might help you figure out where to look for bugs in your asm.  Or you could just single-step your asm in a debugger and see what loop its getting stuck in, and what values are in registers.  This question is pretty weird, you're asking us to figure out why your buggy asm function behaves differently without showing it or showing the compiler's asm out

Comment: Leo: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47845728/edit) your question with relevant source (you can create placeholder assembly which will just return the argument precision), build it, make sure it shows the same problem, and then put the full buildable source into question + your target platform + how you build executable, so anyone with access to similar platform can try to reproduce your problem. @PeterCordes I'm saving "close" vote to a moments when OP doesn't communicate and doesn't improve the Q. Once the Q gets closed, it seems to me it's very difficult to bring back life into it.

Comment: Thinking about it, just returning `precision` is probably not enough, show reasonable amount of original assembly, so one can see how you process the argument and how you return result. The calculation code itself shouldn't be interesting, let's pretend you have no bug there. And EDIT your **QESTION**, don't post it as answer, that will get downvoted too. Does the edit work for you?

Comment: Are you sure your loop doesn't just get stuck because of FP rounding errors, if you make precision too small?  You're rounding to a qword `double` all the time instead of keeping your values in x87 registers (as 80 bit `long double`), so it wouldn't surprise me if it never converges to x86's internal Pi constant (from `fldpi`).

Comment: For weird return values, you're leaving the x87 stack unbalanced because you load multiple things inside the loop, and don't pop them before returning.  Perhaps that's breaking printf, if it's not using SSE2.  Balance the x87 stack with the `p` versions of instructions instead of using `finit` at the top of the loop.

Comment: And still missing platform.. from the screenshot it looks like windows, but then it can be either 32 bit or 64 bit, which does change the calling convention considerably (interface between C and ASM).

Comment: NASM version 2.11.06 compiled on Oct 20 2014
              gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're accessing the function arg incorrectly, offset by 4 bytes.  When you make a stack frame, **the first arg is at `[ebp+8]`, but you're loading from `[ebp+12]`**.  (This applies to all calling conventions that pass args on the stack.  I think 32-bit mingw does that for `double` by default.)

This means the `double` value you're using as `precision` has its high 4 bytes from whatever the caller happened to leave on the stack above the 8-byte arg slot.   This explains why changes in the caller affect the behaviour of your function, and why you can get an infinite loop: if the bytes you load happen to represent a very small `double`, your loop never exits.

The low 4 bytes (32 least-significant bits of the mantissa) come from the top 4 bytes of what the caller passed.

You would have easily found this with a debugger by looking at registers and noticing the value you load wasn't the value the caller passed.  Also, @Ped7g's suggestion to just try returning `precision` in a trivial asm function would have found the problem, too.